# Runtime Warning Using power with Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm using power function from numpy and i'm obtaining a warning message. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np


def f(x, n):
    factor = n / (1. + n)
    exponent = 1. + (1. / n)
    f1_x = factor * np.power(0.5, exponent) - np.power(0.5 - x, exponent)
    f2_x = factor * np.power(0.5, exponent) - np.power(x - 0.5, exponent)
    return np.where((0 <= x) & (x <= 0.5), f1_x, f2_x)

fv = np.vectorize(f, otypes='f')
x = np.linspace(0., 1., 20)
print(fv(x, 0.23))
```

And this is the warning message:

> E:\ProgramasPython3\LibroCientifico\partesvectorizada.py:8:
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power   f2_x = factor *
>   np.power(0.5, exponent) - np.power(x - 0.5, exponent)
>   E:\ProgramasPython3\LibroCientifico\partesvectorizada.py:7:
>   RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power   f1_x = factor *
>   np.power(0.5, exponent) - np.power(0.5 - x, exponent) [-0.0199636 
>   -0.00895462 -0.0023446   0.00136486  0.003271    0.00414007
>     0.00447386  0.00457215  0.00459036  0.00459162  0.00459162  0.00459036
>     0.00457215  0.00447386  0.00414007  0.003271    0.00136486 -0.0023446  -0.00895462 -0.0199636 ]

I don't know what is the invalid value. And I don't know how to specify that with where numpy function f2_x is only valid for values between >0.5 and <= 1.0.
Thanks

Comment: It's running fine for me - Python 3.4.1, numpy 1.9.0, Win8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are trying to take a non-integer power of a negative number. Apparently this doesn't work in earlier versions of Python/Numpy if you don't explicitly cast the value to be complex. So you will have to do something like

`np.power(complex(0.5 - x), exponent)`<strike>`.real`</strike>

**EDIT :** Since your values will be truly complex (not some real number + some tiny imag part), I think you would want to either use the complex (but then the `<=`) later on gets kind of difficult, or you would want to catch the case where the base is negative in some other way.

Comment: +1 or you can simply do `x = x.astype(np.complex128)`

Comment: I've already installed numpy latest but i obtain the same error adding real. Strange thing, I'm using windows 8.1 64 bits and Pycharm detects me numpy 0.8 but I've already installed the latest version for Python 3.4.2 64 bits. Thanks

Comment: @Tobal did you also put the `complex()` cast? That's actually the important part. If that doesn't work, try @Saullo Castro's version. I'm pretty sure the negative argument is the problem (I get the same error when trying it).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks  a lot everyone, here's the solution using a piecewise function against where from numpy, and using np.complex128 as mentioned **@Saullo**

```
   import numpy as np


    def f(x, n):
        factor = n / (1. + n)
        exponent = (n + 1.) / n
        f1_x = lambda x: factor * \
            np.power(2., -exponent) - np.power((1. - 2. * x) / 2., exponent)
        f2_x = lambda x: factor * \
            np.power(2., -exponent) - np.power(-(1. - 2. * x) / 2., exponent)
        conditions = [(0. <= x) & (x <= 0.5), (0.5 < x) & (x <= 1.)]
        functions = [f1_x, f2_x]
        result = np.piecewise(x, conditions, functions)
        return np.real(result)

    x = np.linspace(0., 1., 20)
    x = x.astype(np.complex128)
    print(f(x, 0.23))
```

The problem is  when the base from a power is negative then np.power doesn't work fine and you obtain the warning message. I expect this is useful for everyone.